# error with dataimport when using multiple cores

Tags: solr

For some time I have used a single core, and "dataimport" worked well. But when it took two different index, I installed the second core, and there was an error:

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler'

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the core can access the dataimport jar files. This easiest way to ensure this is to put the jar file in coredir/lib , where coredir is the dir pointed to as instanceDir from solr.xml.

Comment: I think your suggestion might be misleading. The coredir you mentioned is the solr_home, while usually each core is in a subdirectory within it. The lib are in a single point, shared between all cores.

Comment: no, the core can be located at any place as mentioned the location is configured from solr/solr.xml

Comment: So you mean that the lib dir should be replicated for each core?

Comment: Yes If it is specific to the core, otherwise we can load it in shared solr_home/lib as well. Disclaimer! I haven't tried the later method in a multicore setup yet, but it should work fine.

Comment: Well, usually you don't need different libs for each core, that's why I've always used the shared way.